# Asymptote of a line?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fake-proofs, rational-functions

If a rational function is defined as $f(x) = \frac{p(x)} {q(x)}$ for any two polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$; given $p(x) = 2x+1$ (polynomial of degree 1) and $q(x) = 3$ (polynomial of degree zero), and the fact that a line $mx+n$ is asymptotic to rational function $f(x)$ if $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} [f(x) - (mx + n)] = 0$ then by that definition the oblique asymptote of $\frac{2x+1} {3}$ is $\frac 2 3 x + \frac 1 3$

This can't be right though... can it?

Comment: You mean "oblique asymptote".

Comment: Sorry, that is what I meant to put.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is it the asymptote, the function is of course a straight line, so that $f(x)-mx-n$ is always zero.

It's just not horizontal.

Comment: Various textbooks refer to a non-horizontal linear asymptote as a "slant asymptote" or "oblique asymptote".  It's a little _strange_ to refer to a linear function as "its own asymptote", because the word means "not touched" (from the Greek), so this wouldn't really be true for a line.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner - this may be a bad naming convention, but the mathematical definition doesn't necessitate "not touching". For instance, the function $\sin x /x$ has an asymptote of $Y=0$, even though the function "touches" the line an infinite amount of times.

Comment: "Crossing" an asymptote is not a restriction:  there are numerous rational functions for which their curves cross their horizontal asymptotes somewhere.  The use of "asymptote" relates (at least originally) to the behavior of the curve as the variable "approaches infinity".  Regarding a line as its own asymptote then is not quite a proper use of the word, but what's in a name?  I think, in practice, though, you wouldn't hear someone say that...